# What does "a musical family that never sat down" means?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I was going over [Viriginia Apgar's Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_Apgar) of today's doodle.

In the beginning of Her Early Life and Education, it states that she was a part of "a musical family that never sat down".

I just wonder what it means. Does anyone know?

Comment: Probably implies that the family could never really have a peaceful dinner together, considering a busy father and two sick brothers. The phrase is not idiomatic, so one needs to read the source to know. (-->)

Comment: (-->) Calmes, Selma H (May 2015). "Dr. Virginia Apgar and the Apgar Score: How the Apgar Score Came to Be". *Anesthesia & Analgesia*. 120 (5).

Comment: i cannot find the quote in your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **"A musical family who never sat down"** - 
>     The quote is found here >>> [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a_RbuQ1TPY]
>   Yes indeed it does mean that they were always busy... on the go.

Here is another quote about someone else who never sat down.
[http://fortbridgerrendezvoustintipivillage.com/about-us.html
 
  *"She was so excited to be back on the ranch again.  We called her the energizer bunny, as she never sat down and was always so cheerful and happy to help in any way she could."*